# how to fetch data and display properly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

from the https://www.tvmaze.com/api need to get tv shows base on their genre.
For example
genre action: 4 tv shows/movies
genre drama: 4 tv shows/movies
genre thriller: 4 tv shows/movies

This api do not have genre a api call resposnse.

This is example of the response:http://api.tvmaze.com/shows

```
{
"id": 1,
"url": "http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/1/under-the-dome",
"name": "Under the Dome",
"type": "Scripted",
"language": "English",
"genres": [
"Drama",
"Science-Fiction",
"Thriller"
],
"status": "Ended",
"runtime": 60,
"premiered": "2013-06-24",
"officialSite": "http://www.cbs.com/shows/under-the-dome/",
"schedule": {
"time": "22:00",
"days": [
"Thursday"
]
},
"rating": {
"average": 6.5
},
"weight": 97,
"network": {
"id": 2,
"name": "CBS",
"country": {
"name": "United States",
"code": "US",
"timezone": "America/New_York"
}
},
"webChannel": null,
"externals": {
"tvrage": 25988,
"thetvdb": 264492,
"imdb": "tt1553656"
},
"image": {
"medium": "http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/81/202627.jpg",
"original": "http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/81/202627.jpg"
},
"summary": "<p><b>Under the Dome</b> is the story of a small town that is suddenly and inexplicably sealed off from the rest of the world by an enormous transparent dome. The town's inhabitants must deal with surviving the post-apocalyptic conditions while searching for answers about the dome, where it came from and if and when it will go away.</p>",
"updated": 1573667713,
"_links": {
"self": {
"href": "http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/1"
},
"previousepisode": {
"href": "http://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/185054"
}
}
},
```

How I can make the api call to get this result in javascript Vue?

Comment: check this out: https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html

Comment: Please dive into the basics of SPA’s

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      info: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('https://api.tvmaze.com/shows')
      // You can change the link above to your API
      // Note: I've found it sometimes only works with HTTPS
      .then(response => (this.info = response))
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.20.0/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-quHCp3WbBNkwLfYUMd+KwBAgpVukJu5MncuQaWXgCrfgcxCJAq/fo+oqrRKOj+UKEmyMCG3tb8RB63W+EmrOBg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ info }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      info: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('https://api.tvmaze.com/shows')
      // You can change the link above to your API
      // Note: I've found it sometimes only works with HTTPS
      .then(response => (this.info = response))
  }
})
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.20.0/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-quHCp3WbBNkwLfYUMd+KwBAgpVukJu5MncuQaWXgCrfgcxCJAq/fo+oqrRKOj+UKEmyMCG3tb8RB63W+EmrOBg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ info }}
</div>
```